# Python manual EOF in .py file

Tags: python

I have a big .py file, and I want Python to ignore everything after, say, 15th line...
Something like this:

```
import this
import that

def foo():
    ...

def foobar():
    ...    

MANUAL_EOF_HERE_SO_DEAR_PYTHON_PLEASE_IGNORE_THE_REST_OF_THIS_FILE

def bar():
    ....
```

Is there such a thing? Using python 2.7.

Comment: Are you going to be reading in the file or do you want something that will function the same as commenting out the lines past the manual break?

Comment: @Jeff the file gets executed by python, so something like commenting out the rest of the lines. something like a "return" from file.

Comment: You have a very descriptive constant in your pseudocode!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three choices:

1. Comment out every line after a certain point by inserting a # at the start of it (which should be easy in your text editor)
2. Put the entire block of code into a block quote by putting `"""` at the start and end of it (this won't work if there are triple-quoted regions within the code) ETA: Better yet, use `'''` (triple single quotes)
3. Use `sys.exit()` to stop the program at some point (having done `import sys` earlier). Note that this will stop the code from executing, but will *not* stop it from being interpreted by Python. Thus, any syntax errors below that line could still cause the program to break.

Comment: (2) can be made a little easier in practice by using ''' for bulk commenting like this instead--- at least if you typically use """ for docs and multiline strings, like I do.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
import sys

def foo():
...

sys.exit()

# do not run

def bar():
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment out those lines by inserting a `#` at the beginning of each. This is a simple, one-key operation in most text editors. For example, in the IDLE editor that comes with Python, just select the code you don't want to run and press Alt-3.

Comment: +1 for hotkeys. `alt+4` uncomments those same lines, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing `big.py` from some other file? If so, just use `from big.py import specific, functions, and, classes`.

If you are running it from the command line:

`head -15 | python -`